# Reading and writing variables from file

Tags: file, python-2.7, save

I'm trying to create a register/login CLI and I don't understand why don't the variables I write inside the register file work later when I try to use them in the login part.

I thought it was as easy as writing `abc="xyz"` and then reading that file, but it seems it's not like that.

```
###RegOrLog###
RegOrLog = str(raw_input('[Register/Log]:'))

###register the user detail###
if RegOrLog in('r', 'reg', 'register'):
    reguser = raw_input('username:')
    regpass = raw_input('password:')
    regage = int(raw_input('age:'))
    reggender = str(raw_input('gender:'))

###creating file for the user###
    f = open(reguser, 'w')
    f.write('password =' + repr(regpass) + '\n')
    f.write('age =' + repr(regage) + '\n')
    f.write('gender =' + repr(reggender) + '\n')
    f.close()
    RegOrLog = 'log'

###login as a user###
if RegOrLog in('l','log','login'):
    loguser = raw_input('Login username:')
    regpass = raw_input('password:')

#registered user#
    regeduser = open(loguser, 'r')
    regeduser = regeduser.read()
    if regpass == password:
        print 'Welcome', loguser
        print 'You are', gender
        print 'You are', age,'years old'
```

Comment: Please, make yourself clearer. Is that code working? If not, what is the problem with it?

Comment: The code is working but I don't know how to use the variable inside the file that I saved.

Comment: What variable? In your file you are saving a couple of data, not a unique variable. I just can't get my head round to your problem.

Comment: inside the file that the program create;
password = syafiq12
age = 19
gender = male

i want to use the age and gender to able it to print

Comment: i want the program to able to read the password save in the file

Comment: Ok. I have understood your question. I'm going to write an answer for you.

Comment: I have a nice answer for you, but you still have to code the file name stuff  which you already had in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now understand your problem. A text file just saves plain data, therefore, you cannot create a file writing like if it were a Python file, with a variable definition, and expect that when you read the file again all those variables will be initialized. Python will only read the data and assign it to a variable which will contain all the text you originally wrote into that file.

So, summing up, you are treating a text file like a python file and expecting python to execute the text file and create a variable.

But that does not work like that. You have to store the data in a database-like file (or in a database itself), then read it, and by means of data parsing, extract the variables you had written into the text file before.

You can do that manually, which is not very nice, or you can use a Python module called Pickle, which handles pretty much everything you would write yourself, and so you would only have to make use of this module in your code.

If you search for the Pickle module in Google, the Python.org website provides a very nice example of its usage:

```
#Pickle Example

# Save a dictionary into a pickle file.
import pickle

favorite_color = { "lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red" }

pickle.dump( favorite_color, open( "save.p", "wb" ) )

# Load the dictionary back from the pickle file.

favorite_color = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) )
# favorite_color is now { "lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red" }
```

So, how would you use it in your code? This easy:

```
# RegOrLog

import pickle # new line!
RegOrLog = raw_input('[Register/Log]:') # why str()?

# register the user detail
if RegOrLog in('r', 'reg', 'register'):
    reguser = raw_input('username:') # raw_input gives string by default, if you want other data type then you do have to convert it.
    regpass = raw_input('password:')
    regage = int(raw_input('age:'))
    reggender =raw_input('gender:')

# creating file for the user
    data = {"username": reguser, "password": regpass, "age": regage, "gender": reggender}
    pickle.dump( data, open( "whatever_file_name", "wb" ) )
    RegOrLog = 'log'

###login as a user###
if RegOrLog in('l','log','login'):
    loguser = raw_input('Login username:')
    regpass = raw_input('password:')

#registered user#
    data = pickle.load( open( "whatever_file_name", "rb" ) )
    if regpass == data["password"]:
        print 'Welcome', loguser
        print 'You are', gender
        print 'You are', age,'years old'
```

Comment: thank you so much sir. i'm able to continue the assignment smoothly

Comment: Oh, one more thing!  Can you give me give me the code to loop if the file  or the username doesn't?

Comment: @Eutos We can your code into a stronger OOP log in system (obviously not the CIA one, :D, I mean better structured code, more readable and expandable). I'll send it to you just when I have a bit of free time.

Comment: its okay sir. This is only for the university assignment, Not a big deal but thanks btw

Comment: RE:Oh, one more thing! Can you give me give me the code to loop if the file or the username doesn't exits inside the file. it suppose to  be this question